# Does this function execute : jQuery(".class").function(); if the class is not found on this page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just a quick question.

I'm wondering if in the following code if unslider() will run if there is no .banner class on the page?

> jQuery(".banner").unslider();

I do not want it to run on pages where there is no .banner class.

Do I need to do something like

> if (jQuery(".banner") > 0){
>    jQuery(".banner").unslider(); 
>   }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it runs and executes the following ([source](http://unslider.com/unslider.js)):

```
$.fn.unslider = function(o) {
    var len = this.length;

    //  Enable multiple-slider support
    return this.each(function(index) {
        //  Cache a copy of $(this), so it 
        var me = $(this);
        var instance = (new Unslider).init(me, o);

        //  Invoke an Unslider instance
        me.data('unslider' + (len > 1 ? '-' + (index + 1) : ''), instance);
    });
};
```

So it does a `.each()` on your collection.

However, if that collection is empty, the function passed to `.each()` will not run and therefore "not much" would describe best what would happen if you run `$('.banner').unslider();`

Btw, it wouldn't make sense to try and "optimize" this by doing a `.length` check unless you're certain that the call will be heavy.

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not get executed if the element is not found.

The plugin method will get called, but since there are no element matching the selector it should not be doing anyting - but it again depends on how the plugin is implemented

Answer (score 0):

Normally the follow up actions wont get executed if the `class` is not available, but doing a preliminary check will be safer one.

You have to like this,

```
if(jQuery(".banner").length > 0){ jQuery(".banner").unslider(); }
```

Or

```
if(jQuery(".banner").length){ jQuery(".banner").unslider(); }
```

Comment: The last condition makes no sense, because all objects are considered truthy in an expression.

Comment: @Jack I thought it would return undefined. Thanks for a new info. But i just want to return what it will return in that context.? Thanks.!

Comment: It returns an empty set, or empty array if you will; but even an empty array is still considered truthy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `length` property to check if element exists.

```
if (jQuery(".banner").length > 0)
{ 
   jQuery(".banner").unslider(); 
}
```

You even do not need to check if it is greater then zero.

```
if (jQuery(".banner").length)
{ 
   jQuery(".banner").unslider(); 
}
```